# Cannot move an element to be closer to a floated element

Tags: css

[image: Image.]

Why can't the `#navbar` be shifted further upwards ? I tried `margin-top` but it didn't work. Only an extremely large value had some effect, but the positioning is too skewed.

The `#container` contains all 3 elements.

```
#container {
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width:790px;
}

#chicklogo {
float:left;
border:1px solid black;
}

#rightext {
float:left;
border:1px solid black;
}

#navbar {
clear:both;
border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't because `#navbar` has `clear:both` and is going to fall under the tallest of the floated elements. From your image, you can see that `#rightext` is taller and `#navbar` sits flush under it.

If you gave the logo and right text the same height then your nav would sit just under both.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [JS Fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/Ksz3b/) a negative `margin-top` which would mean the navbar would overlap the preceding element, even though it is set to `clear: both`.

Ideally, you would reduce the height of the `#righttext` element as it looks like the white-space in that element is causing your layout issue, but the negative margin-top can also work if that isn't possible.